# Passing String with Double Quotes from Window.Parent

Tags: asp.net, vbscript

There are some instances in which a user will have double quote in their name. this unfortunately is a downstream system and I have no control over that.

I am calling a method in VBScript

```
Call window.parent.CompletedCallBack("FOUND","EXAMPLE""D.TS200")
```

The ASP.Net method that the above code calls changes the second parameter to

```
EXAMPLE\"D.TS200.
```

what is happening to cause this? there is no other code between the call and the method that could be doing this. Is there something inherent in window.parent that would do this?

Answer (score 0):

You should use '\"' instead of `"""`.  `\` is a scape character in javascript.

So your code becomes

```
window.parent.CompletedCallBack("FOUND","EXAMPLE\"\"D.TS200")
```

### Edit 1.

You can use regular expression to replace text `""` to corresponding

```
    .replace(/["']/g, "")
```

More about scape character in javascirpt

1. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/2yfce773%28v=vs.94%29.aspx
2. http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_strings.asp

Comment: what do you want to say? which is your current code?

Comment: sClientCallbackCode = "Call window.parent.CompletedCallback(""FOUND"",""" & Replace(sCurrentIndexNo, """", """""") & """)"

this is where if it finds a " in the string it creates a extra ". however when it gets called a excape \ is generated. what do you suggest changing this too?

Comment: the code is VBScript like i mentioned above.. this is the actually code..my original post i just had what the code rendered.

Comment: for some reason it goes from EXAMPLE""D.TS200" to EXAMPLE\"D.TS200" after the window.parent.CompletedCallback is called